# Almacenar espacio en blanco con cin.getline

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++

Necesito apoyo para poder almacenar varios datos en un `cin`, separados por un espacio en blanco?

**CODIGO:**

```
cout << "\n\tEscriba Curp de cada integrante de la familia separado por un espacio " << i + 1 << ":";
cin.getline(*curp,18); >> usuario[i].curp;
```

**ERROR:**

> curp was not declared in this escope error
>      expected primary-expression before '>>' token

Si no uso el `.getline(*curp,18);` todo funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es claro y conciso. Tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlo:

> curp was not declared in this escope error
>      expected primary-expression before '>>' token

Sería

> curp no ha sido declarada en este contexto error
>      se esperaba una expresión primaria antes del símbolo '>>'

El error dice claramente que estás usando la variable `curp` pero la variable no existe donde usas dicha variable.

```
cin.getline(*curp,18); >> usuario[i].curp;
//           ~~~~ <--- 'curp' no existe en este contexto
//                   (curp was not declared in this escope)
```

La segunda parte del error hace referencia la uso del operador de extracción de datos (`>>`) indicando que esperaba una expresión antes del mismo; se queja porque en tu código no hay ninguna expresión a su izquierda:

```
cin.getline(*curp,18); >> usuario[i].curp;
//                   ~^~ <--- nada a la izquierda de '>>'
//          (error expected primary-expression before '>>' token)
```

Tal y como está estructurado tu código, me da la sensación que querías hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::cin >> usuario[i].curp;
```